# recyclerview not visible at run time

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, data-binding

I implemented a simple recyclerview using databinding using kotlin language.
In xml, recyclerview seems to be the default,
but when I run it, it doesn't show up as default.
Other buttons and views included in the fragment appear normally when executed, but only the recyclerview is not visible. Which part is wrong?

```css
class WorkFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentWorkBinding? = null

    private val binding get() = _binding!!




    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        _binding = FragmentWorkBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root


        return view
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        val data = mutableListOf<WorkList>()

        val adapter = WorkAdapter()

        adapter.data = data

        binding.recycler1.adapter = adapter

        binding.recycler1.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())


       

    }



    }
```

```html
class WorkAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<WorkAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    var data = mutableListOf<WorkList>()

    class ViewHolder(val binding: RecyclerviewWorkItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(workList: WorkList) {
            binding.tvStarttime.text = workList.Starttime
            binding.tvAdmin.text = workList.Admin
            binding.tvPart.text = workList.Part
            binding.tvStoptime.text = workList.Stoptime
            binding.tvWorkers.text = workList.Workers.toString()
        }
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): WorkAdapter.ViewHolder {

        val binding = RecyclerviewWorkItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: WorkAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(data[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return data.size
    }

//    fun replaceList(newList: MutableList<WorkList>) {
//        data = newList.toMutableList()
//        notifyDataSetChanged()
//    }


}
```

Is there something wrong with my code?
For reference, I just used a fragment, not an activity.

Comment: Because you are passing an empty list into the adapter. So your reyclerview is not showing up.

Comment: I don't understand what an empty list means. Do I need to modify main?

Comment: I entered each data value in the wow fragment and it looks normal. This seems to be my rudimentary mistake. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its typically for the `RecyclerView` to behave like its hidden but actually its not. the reason is you are passing an empty list so the recycler will not be extended or show because there is no items in the list.